# React Native JSON Filtering

Tags: react-native

I'm in the learning process of React Native and working on filtering through a JSON feed. I am able to filter down to a group of data, but I am looking to filter further within that group. At "filteredItem" I am able to get the example below.

{"$id":"3","num":256,"event":"1234","description":"example description","startdate":"2018","enddate":"2019"}

If I wanted to filter down to the event number similar to how I am displaying the whole group of info how would I do that?

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('myurl')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                filteredItem: responseJson.filter(item => item.$id == 3),

            }, function () {
            });

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View>
                <Text>
                 {JSON.stringify(this.state.filteredItem, null, 2)}
                </Text>                                                                                                                                                                                  
        </View>)

}
```

}

Comment: if you `let data = {"$id":"3","num":256,"event":"1234","description":"example description","startdate":"2018","enddate":"2019"}` , then `data.event` will give you `1234` is this is what you looking?

Comment: This is what I'm looking at doing, however if I filter my data down to a single array (like your example), and attempt to display this.state.filteredItem.event I get nothing.

Comment: What is `this.state.filteredItem` ?

Comment: filteredItem is my array. It's been filtered down from the original JSON data. It's on line 7 in the example code above.

Comment: is your HTML is like this `<Text>{this.state.filteredItem}</Text>`

Comment: Correct, that is what I tried displaying.

Comment: can you try `console.log(this.state.filteredItem)` on the callback function of setState

Comment: I get an error "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as React child."

Comment: try `console.log(this.state.filteredItem.event)`

Comment: Same error unfortunately.

Comment: i am not understanding where its getting failed. Could you please create a sandbox for this . here an example https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6 with you data

Comment: Updated with an example JSON feed from Facebook.

Comment: Where is sandbox link yo check?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/z36r9yr7qx

Comment: Update your text like this `<Text>
          {this.state.filteredItem.map(item=>item.id)}
        </Text>` it will work

Comment: That works, thank you!!!

Comment: I will add it as an answer.. accept the answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your text like this

```
<Text>
   {this.state.filteredItem.map(item=>item.id)}
</Text>
```

Change the `item.id` to which ever prop you want

Answer (score 1):

This will filter item $id == 3 and item event == 1234.

```
filteredItem: responseJson.filter(item => item.$id == 3 && item.event == 1234)
```

You can play around with responseJson to achieve what array you want.

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('myurl')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        // Put logic to process the responseJson here before setState
        console.log(responseJson)
        let filteredResponseJson = responseJson.filter(item => item.$id == 3)
        console.log(filteredResponseJson)

        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            filteredItem: filteredResponseJson,
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help I appreciate it. I think I didn't ask my question very well. I'm looking to save a single object within the array I've filtered down to, into a variable. So I could display just "1234" for event.